# Scratched the paint off the wall. How to proceed?

Tags: repair, painting

I accidentally scratched the paint from the wall, chipping it and exposing the white paint below. The wall is slightly yellow and "bumpy", so to say. The scratched area is the size of a coin. I have the fragments of the paint, but I am unsure if they can be useful for something.

My question is: what kind of paint should I get and how can I match the color so that it does not stand out on the wall ? I can provide pics if needed.

Comment: If you can't get an exact match (but you can get very close), the worse case is painting the entire wall. You only need to paint to the edges/corners, as the way the light affects the wall color when the wall changes directions will mask any minor differences in actual color.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things to consider.  First, with regards to color, is how old the paint job is.  After the initial cure (during which the color usually darkens slightly), paint will yellow over time, and it also accumulates dirt and debris which further affect its color.  Smoking in the house speeds this up.   What this means is that older paint is harder to match generally.  When it comes to color matching, keep this in mind and if possible, let the store doing the color matching (using the chips you saved) know about the age as they might suggest slightly altering the color.  Working in your favor is the size of the damage - something this small won't be as noticeable as say a large 12"x12" patch.

Next up is texture - it sounds like your paint was applied with a roller originally, so you should be sure to use a roller on your patch.  If you use a brush then the texture difference will be more noticeable.

The above two techniques should help you blend the patch, though it will still be noticeable to some degree.  If you are a perfectionist then the only "right" way to do it is just re-paint the entire wall/section.

Comment: It's brand new paint. the color is as applied.

Comment: If the repainted area as described above is still noticeable, consider painting a section of the wall, top to bottom and ending in an area where there is little painted surface (at a door frame or window frame).

Comment: @bib: No, I need to hack it somehow. One thing I was thinking about is to scratch paint from other non-visible areas with a knife, slightly, as a powder form. Then I need to make a new small amount of paint from the powder, but I need a binder of some sort.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to make your own paint - any paint store will color match

Comment: also, maybe this is a dumb question, but if it's brand new, don't you have any left?

Comment: @Steven: the owner repainted just before I moved in. I tried a paint I found at the local hardware store, but it's slightly too yellow. It was the best match among the available. I think that adding some slight white should at least mask the scratch.

Comment: You should be able to take a paint chip to a paint store who will scan it with a computer. The software outputs the color formula for a specific paint, and they mix it custom for you - the result should be very close to a perfect match.

Comment: @Steven: unfortunately the only shop I have close at hand and I am able to access does not provide this service. Also, people here don't understand English, and I already had a hard time to explain them what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Most good paint shops will do a colour-matching service if you bring along the fragment you have.

You will be able to tell whether it is gloss or matt (or the assistant at the paint shop will)